# jQuery increase value only at clicked div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to increase value, by clicking plus or minus picture. It works fine when it's only one "item_quantity" block at the page. But it works incorrectly if I wanna add another "item_quantity" block.

JS code that increase value:

```
$('.item_quantity .plus').click(function() {
  var num = parseInt($('.item_quantity .quan_numb').text());
  $('.item_quantity .quan_numb').text(num + 1);
});
```

http://codepen.io/Vlasov/pen/dvogmp?editors=1010

Comment: You are using class selector to select value. Try using more specific in selector i.e use id selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().find('.quan_numb')
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZeGqmd?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.item_quantity .plus').click(function() {
  var num = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.quan_numb').html());
  $(this).parent().find('.quan_numb').html(num + 1);
});
$('.item_quantity .minus').click(function() {
  var num = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.quan_numb').html());
  if (num > 1) {
    $(this).parent().find('.quan_numb').html(num - 1);
  }
});
```

```css
.minus img, .plus img{
  width: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.quan_numb{
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item_quantity fll">
  <span class="minus">
   <img src="http://www.sammy-icon.com/catalog/view/theme/default/image/icon/minus.png" alt="">
 </span>
  <span class="quan_numb">1</span>
  <span class="plus">
    <img src="http://www.sammy-icon.com/catalog/view/theme/default/image/icon/plus.png" alt="">
 </span>
</div>
<div class="item_quantity fll">
  <span class="minus">
   <img src="http://www.sammy-icon.com/catalog/view/theme/default/image/icon/minus.png" alt="">
 </span>
  <span class="quan_numb">1</span>
  <span class="plus">
    <img src="http://www.sammy-icon.com/catalog/view/theme/default/image/icon/plus.png" alt="">
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```js
$('.item_quantity .plus').click(function() {
  var num = parseInt($(this).siblings('.item_quantity .quan_numb').text());
  $(this).siblings('.item_quantity .quan_numb').text(num + 1);
});
$('.item_quantity .minus').click(function() {
  var num = parseInt($(this).siblings('.item_quantity .quan_numb').text());
  if (num > 1) {
    $(this).siblings('.item_quantity .quan_numb').text(num - 1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item_quantity fll">
  <span class="minus">
   <img src="http://www.sammy-icon.com/catalog/view/theme/default/image/icon/minus.png" alt="">
 </span>
  <span class="quan_numb">1</span>
  <span class="plus">
    <img src="http://www.sammy-icon.com/catalog/view/theme/default/image/icon/plus.png" alt="">
 </span>
</div>

<div class="item_quantity fll">
  <span class="minus">
   <img src="http://www.sammy-icon.com/catalog/view/theme/default/image/icon/minus.png" alt="">
 </span>
  <span class="quan_numb">1</span>
  <span class="plus">
    <img src="http://www.sammy-icon.com/catalog/view/theme/default/image/icon/plus.png" alt="">
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the class selector for selecting the quantities.
You need to be a touch more specific, and reference each individual quantity.

You can find the closest `.quan_numb` by performing:

`var quan_numb = $(this).closest(".item_quantity").find(".quan_numb");`

Which finds the closest parent with class `item_quantity`, then finds the child `quan_num`.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMbxyW?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

It work incorrect because you are using Class use Id instead of class

```
$('#item_quantity1 .plus').click(function() {
var num = parseInt($('#item_quantity1 .quan_numb').text());
$('#item_quantity1 .quan_numb').text(num + 1);
});
```

If you want to add more use different Id's

Answer (score 0):

It because jQuery will return an array if the selector belongs to multiple elements. Use the following code to specify the element that is paired with the button.

```
var num = parseInt($(this).siblings('.quan_numb').text());
```

[See on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpqOmO?editors=1010)